# Count equal Regex matches

Tags: powershell, object, count

I'm currently looking for a way to count equal regex matches and output them in a table or something similar.

My regex looks like this:

```
$regex = "\A[[]{1}[0-9]{2}[.]{1}[0-9]{2}[.]{1}[0-9]{2}[,]{1}\s[0-9]{2}[:]{1}"
```

My Powershell code looks like this at the moment and outputs just all the matches the script finds.

```
((Select-String $content -Pattern $regex -AllMatches).Matches).value
```

The output the script gives me looks like this (shortened):

```
[02.12.21, 11:
[02.12.21, 11:
[02.12.21, 11:
[02.12.21, 13:
[02.12.21, 13:
[02.12.21, 13:
[02.12.21, 13:
[02.12.21, 13:
[02.12.21, 13:
[02.12.21, 13:
```

I would like to output something similar like this:

```
[02.12.21, 11: (3 times)
[02.12.21, 13: (7 times)
```

Can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The cmdlet `Group-Object` will do what you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As noted in comments, you can use [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.2):

```
$matchValues = @(
    '[02.12.21, 11:'
    '[02.12.21, 11:'
    '[02.12.21, 11:'
    '[02.12.21, 13:'
    '[02.12.21, 13:'
    '[02.12.21, 13:'
    '[02.12.21, 13:'
    '[02.12.21, 13:'
    '[02.12.21, 13:'
    '[02.12.21, 13:'
)

$matchValues | Group-Object | ForEach-Object { '{0} ({1} times)' -f $_.Name, $_.Count }
```

Output:

```
[02.12.21, 11: (3 times)
[02.12.21, 13: (7 times)
```

Each group object's `Name` property contains the unique value, while its `Count` property gives you the number of instances of this value.

Finally you can use the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#format-operator--f) `-f` to produce the desired output.